# How to get inputs from thymeleaf without Ambigous Handler error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to get a value from thymeleaf input into my java class.

**Simple script from thymeleaf**

```
  <h1>Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/index}" th:object="${emails}" method="post">
    <p>Enter Emails: <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```

How would I be able to retrieve emails into my java class?

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class IndexController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getdata() throws IOException {
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
    model.addObject("emails", new MailModel());
        return model;
}

@PostMapping("/index")
    public String emailSubmit(@ModelAttribute MailModel emails) {
        System.out.println(emails.getEmail());

        return "index";
    }
```

**Error Message**

```
Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/': {public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.web.controller.IndexController.getdata() throws java.io.IOException, public java.lang.String com.spring.web.controller.IndexController.emailSumbit(com.spring.web.model.MailModel)}
```

My Application is created with Springboot, Java, and Thymeleaf. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible that ModelandView does not work with PostMapping? I also followed https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ and I got that sample working, but when I tried to follow the logic and implement into my project. It did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before declaring your controller, you are setting the RequestMethod to GET everywhere. On the methods you are setting them again, which is ambigous.

Remove the `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)` in line 2. This should fix the mentioned problem.

Comment: Wow, silly me. That was a very silly mistake that took me hours of frustration. Thank you, Problem solved.

Comment: No problem! But please mark the question as "solved", so that other SO users know that this question as a correct answer :)

Comment: Is there any reason when I click the submit button I get an error saying " Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'emails' available as request attribute"? In my POJO my variable name is "email".

Comment: I can only guess on this. I'd suggest you to open a new question though or looking it up on google. Mostly the problem is that an email object should be avaiable in your method head. eg `getdata(MailModel email){}`